# Solr Cores Locking. v 9.0.2

Tags: solr

We have our SOLR server running on an Azure App Service. Occasionally the cores will lock. This can be resolved by a restart but I am hoping that there is some configuration that can help to prevent this. Did anyone experience this?

The SOLR is running as a single instance with no scaling or clustering.

```
sitecore_core_index: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Index dir 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\server\solr\sitecore_core_index\data\index/' of core 'sitecore_core_index' is already locked. The most likely cause is another Solr server (or another solr core in this server) also configured to use this directory; other possible causes may be specific to lockType: native
```

Comment: Using solr in azure web apps is not recommended.

Comment: I get that and we do have a plan to SearchStax in the future. Was hoping there might be an interim solution to make it more stable

Comment: Unfortunately Azure Web Apps is not the right choice for Solr to begin with. You are much better off spinning up a dummy VM for now. A Dev instance of SearchStax Solr is actually priced very well, to a point that it's not worth the headache going through any other processes.

Comment: I have the same issue with Sitecore 9.0.2 and solr, indexes are just spontaneously locking and I have to restart solr server to get everything up and running again. While crawling the logs I've found out that XConnect is probably the reason. Perhaps, it's making too many requests per seconds. This is just my assumption. Have you found the solution to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

I've just blogged about this after talking to Sitecore support regarding this issue, they said:

1. Make sure the Azure Web App is not scaled out (instance count should be set to 1).
2. Make sure the environment variable `WEBSITE_DISABLE_OVERLAPPED_RECYCLING` is set to 1

We already have our App Service scaled to just one instance but when checking the configuration settings we didn’t have the `WEBSITE_DISABLE_OVERLAPPED_RECYCLING` setting set. So we added this config and set the value to 1.

[image]

This resolved most issues with Solr locking, more info here:

http://www.flux-digital.com/blog/fixing-solr-azure-app-service-core-locking-issues/

**Update:** I still had issues with cores locking occasionally and started on a solution for it using Powershell in a Runbook a while ago and I have now completed this so have blogged here about it:
https://www.flux-digital.com/blog/auto-re-starting-solr-indexes-get-locked-azure-app-service/

The above solution is based on @BikerP's comment below.

Answer (score 2):

You can spin up a Solr using Azure Container Instances for much less than the price of a VM. It is a bit slow, but fine for non-production systems, and you can have a new one in about 5 minutes flat.

This is backed onto an Azure Storage File Share where the actual cores can live.

The PowerShell script below will set you up for less than $50 a month (remember to turn it off when you're not using it).  We have other scripts to start and stop the containers every weekday, which saves about 70% of the price.

You should check on https://hub.docker.com/_/solr for the version closest to what your Sitecore will need. Definitely stay on the same major version, and try to stay on the same minor version.  Revision is not so important.

```
$resGrp   = "development"
$stgAcc   = "mydevstorage"
$stgKey   = "***************************************=="
$stgShareName = "proj123"
$location = "australiaeast"
$image    = "solr:8.1-slim"
$cpus     = 1
$maxRAM   = 2
$solrMem  = ( $maxRAM * 1024 - 256 )

New-AzContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName $resGrp -Name "my-dev-solr" `
   -Image $image -Cpu $cpus -MemoryInGB $maxRAM `
   -DnsNameLabel "my-dev-solr-123" -Port 8983 `
   -Location $location -OsType Linux -RestartPolicy OnFailure `
   -EnvironmentVariable @{ "SOLR_HOME" = "/data/solr"; "SOLR_JAVA_MEM" = "-Xms256m -Xmx$($solrMem)m" } `
   -AzureFileVolumeShareName $stgShareName -AzureFileVolumeAccountCredential ( New-Object PSCredential -ArgumentList @( $stgAcc, (ConvertTo-SecureString $stgKey -AsPlainText -Force )) ) `
   -AzureFileVolumeMountPath "/data"
```

#### But what does this all do?

Glad you asked!

Mostly it's self explanatory but you need an Azure storage account with a "File Share" (not Blob Storage) called, in this case `proj123`. In that share create a folder `solr` and put your core folders in that. In the root `solr` folder you also need the appropriate `solr.xml` file.  You can copy all that stuff from your web app.

One thing though - this is a public-facing, unencrypted, unsecured Solr, so you need to add some Basic authentication as well.

Create a file called `security.json` and put it in the root with `solr.xml`.  The contents needs to look like this:

```
{
 "authentication":{
   "blockUnknown":true,
   "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
   "credentials":{"solr":"***************"},
   "forwardCredentials":false,
   "":{"v":0}
  },
  "authorization":{
    "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
    "user-role":{"solr":"admin"},
    "permissions":[{"name":"security-edit","role":"admin"}]
  }
}
```

More detail about the contents of that file (and a default password you can use) including how to change the password using a URL, can be found in the [Solr Docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/basic-authentication-plugin.html).

Then in Sitecore you need to update your URLs to be `http://user@pwd:hostname:8983/solr` but there's also more info about that in the [Sitecore docs](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/protecting-solr-over-http.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with `Solr` on `Azure PaaS`, my imperfect solution has been to write a `PowerShell` script that runs on an interval to check the returned `JSON` from a Solr ping - to see if it contains the string `status:OK`, if not present the script restarts the app service.
I run the script every 10 minutes and I find it does a restart on average about every 2 weeks or so, although this can vary a lot.
As I said, it's not perfect, but it works for me.

https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/solr/sitecore_master_index/admin/ping

Comment: Can you please share the script?

Comment: @Astle see my updated answer above where I share detailed steps in my blog on how to setup an Azure Runbook with Powershell that auto-restarts Solr if there are any issues.

Answer (score 1):

We can configure the health check in the `Azure` web app to ping if you are using multiple instances the index by following the steps below

1. Go to your Solr web app in Azure Portal
2. Under Monitoring, select Health Check
3. Enable Health Check
4. Set health Probe path to

   `/solr/sitecore_master_index/admin/ping`
5. Set Unhealthy instance removal --> Load balancing threshold to 2 mins (thats the minimum)

[image]

6. Save the changes.

If the ping response is not 200, then Azure will restart the app.

**Note**: Saving this setting will restart the Solr web app

If you are using a Single instance, you can set up Auto-heal as a workaround

more details here https://sitecorepro.com/fix-solr-core-locking/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

We have faced the same issue when we hosted the `SOLR` as an `app service`.

We have simply changed the `lockType: native` to `lockType: single`

Comment: Sitecore support also recommends us to do this. How it goes so far?